# How to make an NPM module with globally accessible types

Tags: typescript, npm

*Keywords: use types from TypeScript module without importing, publishing a package with types only, tell TypeScript to seek types in an NPM module.*

---

I want to publish an NPM module that contains globally accessible types, much like `lib.d.ts`.

What structure should the module have and how do I include it in another project?

If making the types globally visible is just too hard, requiring it with `<reference/>` would be enough, but that didn't work when I tried.

---

In the project where I want to *use* the types, I've got a `src` folder containing all the source code and `bin` folder which contains the output of `tsc`.

The module containing types can have virtually any structure, I don't really care as long as it works.

---

So far I've tried many, many combinations including `export`ing the types, `declare`ing the types, `export declare`ing the types, putting them to `.ts` or to `.d.ts` file, moving them around the package's folder inside `node_modules`, `import`ing them, `<reference/>`ing them, putting them to `rootDirs`… But nothing worked. And the lack of good documentation on this also didn't help.

Comment: have you tried adding them to type roots in your tsconfig.json ? more specific : tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions -> typeRoots

Comment: That gave me `error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'src'` ('src' is the folder where all my code is)

Comment: Have you tried using the `types` property in your package.json? You should just be able to bundle a type declaration with your package - as long as it's in the same directory as your index.js and named `index.d.ts` there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Matt yes, the type package contains the `types` entry and it is pointing to `index.d.ts` which exists and contains the right types. However I still can't access the types.

Answer (score 8):

I had to solve this for my logging library, `winston-jsonl-logger`. It augments the global scope with a global variable called `logger`. I agree that this is one of the hardest (if not the hardest) problem in TypeScript, not least because of lack of sufficient documentation. In this example, I create a library that uses both globally-visible ('script') and module-visible ('module') types. To clarify that [official terminology](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level `import` or `export` declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

### Directory structure

My `src` folder is transpiled into `dist`. `test` is ignored from transpilation.

It is imperative that you typings are named `index.d.ts` and are nested in a folder whose name is the same as your project (which strictly is probably the name specified in `package.json`). That's what structure `typeRoots` will be looking for.

```
.
├── README.md
├── dist
│   ├── Logger.d.ts
│   ├── Logger.js
│   ├── Logger.js.map
│   ├── initLoggers.d.ts
│   ├── initLoggers.js
│   └── initLoggers.js.map
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── Logger.ts
│   └── initLoggers.ts
├── test
│   └── index.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── typings
    └── winston-jsonl-logger
        └── index.d.ts
```

### 'script' typings

Script typings are those that lack a top-level `import` or `export`. They will be visible globally across projects that consume them.

Of course, as they can't use top-level `import` declarations, they are limited in how descriptive they can be; you may often see a lot of `any` used here. This is a problem I'm trying to get solved [in my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675630/augment-module-declarations-with-types-from-an-external-module?noredirect=1#comment98045147_55675630).

```js
// typings/index.d.ts
declare namespace NodeJS {
    export interface Global {
        logger?: any;
        log?: any;
        logInfo?: any;
    }
}
```

If you use `logger` in the global scope, it will be typed as `any` now.

### 'module' typings

Module typings can use top-level `import` or `export`, but they will only be seen if the module gets imported into the project. i.e. they are not visible globally across the project.

```js
// initLoggers.ts
import {Logger} from "./Logger";
import {LogEntry, Logger as WinstonLogger} from "winston";

// Now we can be more descriptive about the global typings
declare global {
    const logger: Logger;
    // LogEntry's interface: { level: string, message: string, data?: any }
    function log(entry: LogEntry): WinstonLogger;
    function logInfo(message: string, data?: any): WinstonLogger;
}

export function initLoggers(){
    global.logger = new Logger();
    global.log = logger.log.bind(logger);
    global.logInfo = (message: string, data?: any) => {
        return logger.log({ level: "info", message, data });
    }
}
```

If you use `logger` in the global scope, it will *still* be typed as `any`, but at least `global.logger` will have proper typings.

To guarantee that these types are made visible across your project `my-project`, make sure that `my-project` imports this file from the `winston-jsonl-logger`; I do it at my app's entrypoint.

### `package.json`

I didn't use the `typings` or `types` field (maybe specifying `"typings": "typings/winston-jsonl-logger/index.d.ts"` would have meant that packages don't have to explicitly declare the path to my typings; I don't know), but I *did* make sure to distribute my folder of typings.

```
{
  "name": "winston-jsonl-logger",
  "version": "0.5.3",
  "description": "TypeScript JSONL logger.",
  "main": "dist/Logger.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "typings"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/logform": "1.2.0",
    "@types/node": ">=9.6.21",
    "ts-node": "7.0.1",
    "typescript": "3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "winston": "3.2.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "3.6.0",
    "winston-elasticsearch": "0.7.4"
  }
}
```

Omitted fields: `repository`, `keywords`, `author`, `license`, `homepage`, `publishConfig`, and `scripts`; otherwise, that's everything.

### `tsconfig.json`

#### For the lib itself

Nothing special. Just your standard `tsc --init` defaults.

#### For projects consuming the lib

Just make sure that you add a `typeRoots` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...All your current fields, but also:
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/winston-jsonl-logger/typings/winston-jsonl-logger"
    ]
  }
}
```

### If you're using `ts-node`

There are further gotchas here. By default, `ts-node` ignores script typings and only imports descendents of the entry-level import (the reason for this is speed/efficiency). You can force it to resolve imports just like `tsc` does by setting the environment variable: `TS_NODE_FILES=true`. Yes, it will run tests slower, but on the other hand, it'll work at all.

If you're using `ts-node` via commandline, declare the `TS_NODE_FILES` environment variable to be `true`. I also had to declare `TS_NODE_CACHE` to be `false`, because of an inexplicable cache bug in `ts-node` (version 7.0.1 – may still be an issue) when it's resolving imports/dependencies.

```sh
TS_NODE_FILES="true" TS_NODE_CACHE="false" TS_NODE_PROJECT="./tsconfigs/base.json" /usr/bin/nodejs --require ts-node/register --inspect=127.0.0.1:9231 src/index.ts --myCustomArg="hello"
```

I'm normally using `ts-node` because I'm testing with Mocha. Here's how I pass environment variables to `ts-node` from Mocha:

```js
// mocha.env.js

/* From: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/185#issuecomment-321566188
 * Via mocha.opts, add `--require mocha.env` in order to easily set up environment variables for tests.
 *
 * This can theoretically be made into a TypeScript file instead, but it seemed to not set the env variable when I tried;
 * perhaps it failed to respect the order of the --require declarations. */
process.env.TS_NODE_FILES = "true"; // Force ts-node to use TypeScript module resolution in order to implictly crawl ambient d.ts files
process.env.TS_NODE_CACHE = "false"; // If anything ever goes wrong with module resolution, it's usually the cache; set to false for production, or upon any errors!
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! I'm going to try that later today! I'm just curious why does your "typings" folder contain another folder named the same as the project?

Comment: From the [`tsconfig.json` docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html): "A *types package* is a folder with a file called `index.d.ts` or a folder with a `package.json` that has a `types` field... If you use an `import "foo"` statement, for instance, TypeScript may still look through `node_modules` & `node_modules/@types` folders to find the `foo` package." They could be a bit more explicit here, but their convention is to denote type packages as `<package name>/index.d.ts`. Stated [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11137#issuecomment-251755605).

Comment: I found out that `import`ing a module file that `<reference/>`s the script with global types is enough, no need to modify the `typeRoots`. However I'm now struggling with the opposite problem which might be just impossible to solve with the current TS  See my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55713045/1137334).

Comment: I'll write a detailed answer and investigate TS Node for this issue shortly.

Comment: @m93a Importing a module that references a script with global-augmenting types may expose types just for that one module, but I wouldn't expect it to make the types visible project-wide. Your new question is a bit harder for me to relate to; if a dependency needs some types, I feel like consumers should get those types, too.

Comment: Well, that's what I thought, but strangely it seems we both were wrong, the types really *are* visible project-wide.

Comment: @m93a (╯ರ ~ ರ）╯︵ ┻━┻ Just second-guessing the compiler at every step here. Really wish the TypeScript team would just provide more ample documentation and ideally some example repos. Maybe worth filing an issue at this rate...

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the other responders here, I have also spent a fair amount of time trying to get this right . My use case is slightly different and I found an alternative way based on what I've seen other libs do.

Posting in case this is useful to anyone else.

---

My goal is slightly different than OP's: I wanted to publish global interfaces types and for the downstream users of my lib to have readily available whenever they are writing types, but I'm not trying to augment `window` or `global`, just publish global ambient types like React does (e.g. you don't have to `import React` to use `React.ComponentType` when writing types).

Here's how I did it:

1. Create the global types you want to publish in some ambient types file. I call mine `ambient.d.ts` and I put it at the root of my project folder. This file is meant to be published alongside the `dist` folder.
2. Create a new types entry-point (`/index.d.ts`) that re-exports your compiled entry-point (`./dist/index.d.ts`) and include in there a triple-slash reference (`/// <reference types="./ambient" />`) to your ambient types file. Also ensure that your `tsconfig.json`'s `include` option has `ambient.d.ts`.
3. When you publish your lib, tell your users to create a `.d.ts` file at the root of their project folder containing a triple-slash reference to your lib. Many `create-*-app` starters already create this file. For example, `create-next-app` creates a `next-env.d.ts` file that already contains triple-slash references. You could tell your users to augment that.

#### Directory structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── initLoggers.ts
├── dist
│   ├── index.d.ts   <-- your compiled index.d.ts file
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.js.map
│   ├── foo.d.ts
│   ├── foo.js
├── ambient.d.ts     <-- write global types here
├── index.d.ts       <-- new types entry point
├── tsconfig.json
```

You'd publish `package.json`, `ambient.d.ts`, `index.d.ts`, and everything inside of `dist`.

#### `/package.json`:

```js
{
  // ...
  "types": "./index.d.ts", // specify the new entry types entry-point
  // ...
}
```

#### `/index.d.ts` and `tsconfig.json` (step 2):

```
// this is the new entry-point for your types
// use the triple-slash reference to bring in your ambient types
/// <reference types="./ambient" />

// re-export your compiled types
export * from './dist';
```

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": { /* ... */ },
  "include": ["./src", "./ambient.d.ts"]
}
```

#### For your downstream users (step 3):

Tell them to create a `blah.d.ts` file and add a triple-slash reference to your lib. As stated above, next.js already has this file and it's called `next-env.d.ts`. You could tell your users to augment that or create a new `*.d.ts` file.

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
// 
/// <reference types="your-published-lib-name" />
//
```

> Alternatively, as other answers suggested, you could tell your users add your lib to the `typeRoots` compiler options in `tsconfig.json` but I prefer the triple-slash reference instead since it doesn't change the default compiler option and it's what I've seen other libs like next.js do.

Answer (score 3):

Spending days to figure it out. I found two ways to do this:

### A- publish a @types/your-module package

works like a charm, won't detail here.

### B- bundle declaration file into your-module

For solution B :

- The compiler exports the declaration to `my-module/<DIST>/index.d.ts`
- Write by hand another declaration file in the module root folder : `my-module/globalTypes/index.d.ts` which will expose the global namespace:

```
// access from window.MyModule
interface Window {
    MyModule: import('my-module/DIST_FOLDER').MyModule
}

// or directly MyModule
declare const MyModule: import('my-module/DIST_FOLDER').MyModule
```

Maybe you spotted it. But yes, you MUST place the global declaration file in a SUB FOLDER of your module.
Why ? Because the `typesRoot` directive crawls the children of the folder you point to.
That means, in your main project, when you set :

```json
{
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./node_modules/my-module"]
}
```

TSC will find `./node_modules/my-module/globalType/index.d.ts` but WON'T FIND `./node_modules/my-module/index.d.ts`

In fact, this is logic, but you can (too) easily miss it in the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots).

[image]

By default, TSC uses the value: `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]`. And there is no declaration in the @types folder.
So it acts the same for all paths you specify.